# Google Calendar JSON Output

Tags: json, calendar

I've created a public calendar on Google and wanted to use it's JSON-File to embed it on my website. You can see it [here](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/tr79slab76bg49f8otabu324mg@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script).

I can't get it running AND what make's me think the problem might not be my JS-Code is that `JSON-Formatter` like `jsonformat.com` or `jsonprettyprint.com` can't render the file. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL you provided returns not JSON but JS which actually emits JSON in the end. Open it in browser and check.

Comment: I thought it was a stupid mistake. Using now alt=json instead of alt=json-in-script and it works as expected. Thanks